# Unit testing an API

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I've got the following Renderer API in a library that I'm writing:

```
class EXPORT Renderer {
  public:
    Renderer(const Renderer &) = delete;
    Renderer &operator=(const Renderer &) = delete;
    virtual ~Renderer();

  protected:
    Renderer() = default;

  public:
    [[nodiscard]] static std::unique_ptr<Renderer> create(const RendererDescriptor &descriptor);

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<SwapChain> createSwapChain(const SwapChainDescriptor &descriptor, const Window &window) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<Buffer> createVertexBuffer(const BufferDescriptor &descriptor, const VertexFormat &format) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<Buffer> createIndexBuffer(const BufferDescriptor &descriptor, Format format) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<Shader> createShaderFromString(const ShaderDescriptor &descriptor, std::string_view source) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<PipelineState> createPipelineState(const PipelineStateDescriptor &descriptor) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<CommandList> createCommandList(const CommandListDescriptor &descriptor) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<Texture> createTexture(const TextureDescriptor &descriptor) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<RenderTarget> createRenderTarget(const RenderTargetDescriptor &descriptor) = 0;

    [[nodiscard]] virtual std::unique_ptr<RenderPass> createRenderPass(const RenderPassDescriptor &descriptor) = 0;
};
```

This Renderer API is implemented inside another library, for example for OpenGL backend:

```
class GLRenderer final : public Renderer {
  public:
    explicit GLRenderer(const RendererDescriptor &descriptor);

    std::unique_ptr<SwapChain> createSwapChain(const SwapChainDescriptor &descriptor, const Window &window) override;

    std::unique_ptr<Buffer> createVertexBuffer(const BufferDescriptor &descriptor, const VertexFormat &format) override;

    std::unique_ptr<Buffer> createIndexBuffer(const BufferDescriptor &descriptor, Format format) override;

    std::unique_ptr<Shader> createShaderFromString(const ShaderDescriptor &descriptor, std::string_view source) override;

    std::unique_ptr<PipelineState> createPipelineState(const PipelineStateDescriptor &descriptor) override;

    std::unique_ptr<CommandList> createCommandList(const CommandListDescriptor &descriptor) override;

    std::unique_ptr<Texture> createTexture(const TextureDescriptor &descriptor) override;

    std::unique_ptr<RenderTarget> createRenderTarget(const RenderTargetDescriptor &descriptor) override;

    std::unique_ptr<RenderPass> createRenderPass(const RenderPassDescriptor &descriptor) override;

  private:
// private members
};
```

Inside `Renderer::create` factory method this OpenGL backend library is loaded and `GLRenderer` is allocated and then returned. How should I go about unit testing this API using GoogleTest?

Comment: What do you mean by "unit testing an API"? You test implementations, not APIs. A test of API would be a theoretical one (checking if it makes sense, if it adheres to rules established for the project, etc.).

Comment: So should the implementation `GLRenderer` class be unit tested then? And also should the API be tested in integration/functional tests?

Comment: For unit tests you should think about sensible usage scenarios and test these. It's quite easy to test return values of the functions for correctness; if you would like to test side effects, then you might have to work with mocks (details in the documentation).   About testing the abstract interface: Maybe you can abstract some usage scenarios away from the concrete implementation (that is: all implementations have to show common behaviour)? Then one might imagine to write these tests against the interface and inject each implementation into the test cases.

Comment: @kaba could you give an example in the answer? I don't have that much experience in unit testing and I'm trying to figure out how could I write unit tests for my library. Here is a link to the repository of my library if it helps: [the library](https://github.com/rafalmaziejuk/nox)

Comment: @RafalMaziejuk I added my idea for the one aspect concerning "testing the API" (a.k.a the interface) as an answer. Sorry to not being able to dig into your complete library and come up with concrete unit tests. As stated: you need to think about usage scenarios for your libraries and design tests around these: does your implementation what it is expected to do in these situations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your request in the comments, for the one aspect of testing multiple given implementations against their common interface, I worked out a small example with a toy interface and 2 toy implementations. Hopefully this can give you a starting point from where you'll be able to move on (you can see this same code [on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eKPaMrKKc)):

```
#include <memory>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

class interface {
    public:
    virtual ~interface()=default;
    virtual long tripleNum(long) =0;
};

class impl0 : public interface {
    public:
    virtual ~impl0()=default;
    long tripleNum(long const inp) override {
        return inp+inp+inp;
    }
};

class impl1 : public interface {
    public:
    virtual ~impl1()=default;
    long tripleNum(long const inp) override {
        return inp*3;
    }
};

static const std::tuple<std::shared_ptr<impl0>,std::shared_ptr<impl1>> PARAMS{
    std::make_shared<impl0>(), std::make_shared<impl1>() };
using TEST_TYPES = ::testing::Types<std::shared_ptr<impl0>,std::shared_ptr<impl1>>;

template <typename T> class ImplTests : public testing::Test
{
  protected:
    ImplTests() : param(std::static_pointer_cast<interface>(std::get<T>(PARAMS))) {}
    std::shared_ptr<interface> param;
};
TYPED_TEST_SUITE(ImplTests, TEST_TYPES);

TYPED_TEST(ImplTests, ensure_that_triple_returns_three_times_the_input) {
    EXPECT_EQ(27,this->param->tripleNum(9));
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

For sure some things can be done a more elegant way (for example you might not need `shared_ptr` here). Anyway, this example should drive the point home.